# Position of logos with baposter class

Tags: titles, baposter

I am using the `baposter` class for my scientific poster but I am struggling with the position of logos.

I want to put 3 logos on the left side of the title and 3 other ones on the right. However, there's always a large space between the last logo on the left and the title. Same problem with the first logo on the right.

I tried using `\hspace{}` but it does not change anything. I also tried `minipage` but it shifts my title on the right or on the left, as if the space between logos and title was incompressible.

Does anyone has a solution ?

Here is my title section :

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------- 

%   TITLE SECTION 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


{ \includegraphics[height=6em]{logo1} \hspace{12pt} \includegraphics[height=4em]{logo2}  \hspace{12pt}  \includegraphics[height=4em]{logo3g}} % First university/lab logo on the left

{\bf Title of my poster \vspace{0.3em}} % Poster title

{\textcolor{blue3}{Authors  \hspace{12pt} \\ 
Institutions }} % Author names and institution

{ \includegraphics[height=5em]{logo4.jpg} \hspace{12pt} \includegraphics[height=6em]{logo5.png} \hspace{3pt} \includegraphics[height=5em]{logo6.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right
```

Comment: Since just a few people use `baposter`, it would be better to add a full document wrapper to the code, starting from `\documentclass`. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5):

The logos can be placed by including them in tabular environment. The following MWE provides a demonstration. To illustrate a range of `baposter` features the MWE does the following:

1. Three logos are placed each side of the title in a `tabular` environment. The `tabular` is used to configure the placement of the logos. The logo grouping on the right uses `multicolumn` to make the logo in the second row span two columns.
2. To more completely illustrate some `baposter` features, three boxes are created. Box 1 is in column 0, row 0 of the poster. Box 2 is below Box 1. Box 2 contains three images arranged in a `tabular` environment, with one of the images spanning two rows using `multirow`. Box 3 spans columns 2 and 3, and is bottom aligned with Box 2. It includes an `itemize` environment list where the text is made to wrap around an image using features of `adjustbox` and `wrapfig`.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a2paper,landscape,fontscale=0.8,margin=1cm]{baposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters
\usepackage{graphicx}    % Required for including images
\usepackage{multicol}    % To demonstrate placement of example images across 2 columns
\usepackage{wrapfig}     % To demonstrate wrapping text around image
\usepackage{adjustbox}   % To demonstrate wrapping text around image
\usepackage{multirow}    % To demonstrate placement of example images across 2 rows
\usepackage{enumitem}    % To create customized list environment 
\usepackage{blindtext}   % Dummy text
\usepackage{arev}        % Sans serif font with heavy weight

\newlength{\strutheight} % for wrapping text around image
\settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut} % for wrapping text around image

\begin{document}

    \background{% this is a user specified background i.e. set background=user in general options (row 32 of code)
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        %the poster background color
        \fill[fill=blue!10!white] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        %the header for the poster title and authors
        \fill [fill=blue!25!white] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\headerheight] current page.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \begin{poster}{
        %general options for the poster
        grid=false,
        columns=6, % how many columns 1-6
        colspacing=4.2mm, % spacing between the columns
        headerheight=0.15\textheight, % the height of the header as a proportion of the page height
        background=user, %user or none or plain
        eyecatcher=true, %turn logos on/off
        %posterbox options
        headerborder=closed, % see the baposter manual for the rest
        borderColor=darkgray,
        headershape=rectangle,
        headershade=plain,
        headerColorOne=darkgray,
        textborder=rectangle,
        boxshade=plain,
        boxColorOne=white,
        headerFontColor=white,
        headerfont=\large\bfseries,
        linewidth=1pt
        }
        %Do not change the layout of the following items, although title and author can span multiple lines
        {The logo on the left
            \begin{tabular}{lll}
              \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} &
              \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} &
              \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
            \end{tabular}
        }
        {Title} %the poster title
        {Authors} %the author(s)      
        {%The logo on the right
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} &
                \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} \\
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
            \end{tabular}
        }

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box1,span=1,column=0,row=0,boxheaderheight=2em]{%
        \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}}
            Box 1
        \end{tabular}
        }
        \blindtext[1]
    \end{posterbox}

    % Put 3 figures in a tabular environment. One figure spans 2 rows.
    \begin{posterbox}[name=box2,span=1,headerColorOne=blue,column=0,below=box1,boxheaderheight=2em]{%
        \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}}
            Box 2
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a} & \multirow[t]{2}{3cm}[-1cm]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}} \\
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box3,span=2,column=1,row=0,bottomaligned=box2,boxheaderheight=4em]{%
        \begin{tabular}{p{14cm}}
            This is Box 3 with a very log header that requires boxheaderheight=4em. This box is bottom aligned with Box 2 and spans columns 2 and 3 (Column number starts at 0).
        \end{tabular}
    }
    % create an itemize list and insert a figure
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=6pt]
        \item \blindtext[1]
            \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
                \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
                \end{wrapfigure}% 
                \strut{}
                \item \blindtext[1]
            \end{adjustbox}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I hope this helps you get started, and welcome to TeX.SE.